# Не могу обратится к ListBox С# MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Цель - сделать отчет в CSV файл.

3 папки:

- Models
  Human.cs
- Viewmodels
  HumanViewModel.cs
- Views
  MainWindow.xaml

Human

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM.Models
{
    class Human : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _firstname;
        private string _surname;
        private string _passport;
        private string _databirth;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstname;
            }
            set
            {
                _firstname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
        public string Surname
        {
            get
            {
                return _surname;
            }
            set
            {
                _surname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
            }
        }
        public string Passport
        {
            get
            {
                return _passport;
            }
            set
            {
                _passport = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Passport");
            }
        }

        public string Databirth
        {
            get
            {
                return _databirth;
            }
            set
            {
                _databirth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Databirth");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

HumanViewModel

```
class HumansViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Human _selectedhuman;
        public ObservableCollection<Human> Humans { get; set; }
        public Human SelectedHuman
        {
            get { return _selectedhuman; }
            set
            {
                _selectedhuman = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHuman");
            }
        }
        public HumansViewModel()
        {
            Humans = new ObservableCollection<Human>
        {
            new Human { FirstName="Иван", Surname="Иванов", Passport="1111-111111",Databirth="1-1-1998"},
            new Human { FirstName="Jahseh ", Surname="Dwayne  ", Passport="2222-222222",Databirth="0-0-1990"}
        };
        }
        public void AddHuman()
        {
            Human human = new Human();
            Humans.Insert(0,human);
            SelectedHuman = human;
        }
        public void DeleteHuman()
        {
            if (_selectedhuman != null)
            {
                Humans.Remove(SelectedHuman);
            }
        }

        public void ReportingInCSV()
        {
            using (StreamWriter myOutputStream = new StreamWriter("Myfile.csv"))
            {
                foreach (var item in ReportBox.item)
                {
                    myOutputStream.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

    }
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MVVM_Example" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding SelectedHuman}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Выбранный элемент" Margin="5,0"  />
            <TextBlock Text="Имя" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Фамилие" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Surname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Паспорт(серия-номер)" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Passport, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Дата рождения(дд.мм.гггг)" Margin="5,0"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Databirth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5,0" />


            <Button Click="Add_Click" Margin="5,0">+</Button>
            <Button Click="Delete_Click" Margin="5,0">-</Button>
            <Button Click="ReportingInCSV" Margin="5,0">Экспорт </Button>

        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="ReportBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Humans}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedHuman}" Margin="0,235,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Surname}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Passport}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Databirth}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs

```
namespace Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new HumansViewModel();
        }
        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((HumansViewModel)DataContext).AddHuman();            
        }
        private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((HumansViewModel)DataContext).DeleteHuman();
        }

        private void ReportingInCSV(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((HumansViewModel)DataContext).ReportingInCSV();
        }
    }

}
```

Собственно в `ListBox` есть информация. Цель: при нажатии на кнопку генерировать все в `csv  file`

```
public void ReportingInCSV()
            {
                using (StreamWriter myOutputStream = new StreamWriter("Myfile.csv"))
                {
                    foreach (var item in ReportBox.item)
                    {
                        myOutputStream.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                    }
                }

            }
```

Но проблема в том что я не могу обратиться к `ListBox'у`. Как будто нет соответствующего модификатора. Как можно реализовать это??

Comment: 1) Вы 2 раза запостили вьюмодель. Модель не показали. 2) Используйте команды вместо обработчиков событий 3) неясно отчего вы решили, что вьюмодель должна знать о какой то части представления. Вы в тот лист биндили `Humans`?  Вот и итерируйте по `Humans` во вьюмдели

Comment: @tym32167 Исправил в вопросе код от `human.cs`. Потому что если писать `humans `будет в файле `Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM.Models.Human    
Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM.Models.Human`

Comment: Поймите одну простую вещь. MVVM создан для того, что бы оградить дизайн (view), от основного кода, разделить все на 3 слоя (Model, View, ViewModel) и *самое главное!* Вы не как не должны из кода обращаться к View элементам, то есть ваше `foreach (var item in ReportBox.item)` уже в корне не верно...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да я знаю попытка к обращению к `listbox` была потому что при обращение к биндингу `humans` выдавало не верный результат, а именно `Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM.Models.Human  
Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM.Models.Human
`

Comment: Я ничего не понял про ваши файлы. Что вам сейчас мешает заменить `foreach (var item in ReportBox.item)` на `foreach (var item in Humans)`?

Comment: @tym32167 Заменил уже и получил отчет в файл который создался Myfile.csv `StreamWriter myOutputStream = new StreamWriter("Myfile.csv")` две строчки `Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM.Models.Human
Tutorial_Wpf_MVVM.Models.Human
`

Comment: Ну а что вы ожидаете, если вы это и пишете здесь? `myOutputStream.WriteLine(item.ToString());` У вашего типа `Human` метод `ToString` не переопределен, вот он и возвращает просто свой тип.

Comment: Переопределяйте `ToString` или пишите `myOutputStream.WriteLine($"{item.Name};{item.Lastname} ... ");`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо вы мне очень помогли, теперь понимаю на сколько мой вопрос был тупой, а что если мне нужно будет например отсортировать по какому либо столбу? как например в SQL ORDER BY где искать ответ ?

Comment: Отсортировать где? При записи в файл? `foreach (var item in Humans.OrderBy(x=>x.Lastname))`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо огромное, вы мне помогли уже во второй раз), всего наилучшего)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Хорошо, что заработало